# Modify a base function in R

Tags: r

This is my question:

How can I modify "dir" base function just for setting a default "pattern" parameter?.

NOTE. I must use the dir base function, not another one.

The reason why i need it is the following (just in case someone suggest other solution):

I need to load GGIR package

```
library(GGIR)
```

When it is loaded, several functions are loaded also. I am using many of these functions (e.g "g.part2"), but I get this error:

```
Error in load(paste0(path, fnames[i])) : 
  bad restore file magic number (file may be corrupted) -- no data loaded
In addition: Warning message:
file ‘desktop.ini’ has magic number '[.She'
  Use of save versions prior to 2 is deprecated
```

I debugged the package and function and I already know what is happening:

When "g.part2" is executed, a directory is created and some files are stored into it. But, when the directory is created, my Windows also creates a hidden file named "desktop.ini" into it (I investigated several days, but I didnt find a way to avoid the generation of the desktop.ini).

Then, the names of the files which were stored into the directory are recovered (including desktop.ini) by using "dir" function. These files are read, and it fails when try to read desktop.ini.

In order to solve that, my first approach was to create a "dir1" function for excluding the desktop.ini by just modifying the default value in the "pattern" parameter from the dir base function. Then I had to modify "g.part2"

```
trace(g.part2,edit=TRUE)
```

… and replace "dir(" by "dir1("

However, similar to "g.part2" there are several functions that I need to use ("g.part3","g.part4","g.part5","g.report.part4"....) and they internally use "dir" function. For me is not viable being "tracing" to many functions every day, in addition, it can not be done programatically, isnt it?

So, I think, the solution (if it is posible) is to modify the dir base function and set a default value for pattern parameter just for excluding desktop.ini file. Doing this, I wont need to modify any of the functions from GGIR package.

Best regards

Comment: Have you tried `dir = function(...)`? That's the easy way to modify a function--just overwrite it with what you want. But getting a package to use your function might be harder. I would suggest modifying `GGIR` instead. There are, perhaps, ways to modify it you haven't considered.

Comment: Are you saying the `library(GGIR)` is returning this error? Or what code exactly is giving you the error? Changing a base function is never a good idea because you could change behavior that other functions depend on.

Comment: I use Windows, dir.create from R and do not suffer from unwanted desktop.ini. Maybe you can file a bug report with the package devs if their code somehow has this side effect?

Comment: The GGIR github page [is here](https://github.com/wadpac/GGIR). You could file an issue with them. If you do need to modify their code, rather than using `trace` to  modify the functions interactively, fork the repo and make all the edits. RStudio's "find in fiiles" should make it pretty quick to find all occurrences that you need to modify.

Comment: MrFlick, Im executing "g.shell.GGIR" function, and internally it calls "g.part2". The error occurs in there. Frank, the desktop.ini is not only created when I use R. When I create a directory manually, this file is created also. I dont know if it is a bug. Many people has the same problem as I investigated. But noone got the solution. @Gregor , sorry, Im quite new in R, what do you mean by "fork the repo", Does RStudio can edit code from a loaded package??

Comment: Re: fork the repo, you go to [their github page](https://github.com/wadpac/GGIR), click the `fork` button in the top right corner, and download your own copy of the package code. You would open it (in RStudio), edit the files you want, then build and install your modified version of the package. (This can all be done in RStudio if you install the helper packages, `devtools`, `roxygen2`, `testthat`, etc.) It wouuld certainly be a learning experience, but if the necessary changes are actually minor, it wouldn't be too bad.

Answer (score 0):

I could modify dir base function by using:

```
trace(base::dir,edit=TRUE)
```

However, for fixing my problem, I didnt modify this base function, I follow instructions in Gregor's comment instead:

> Re: fork the repo, you go to their github page, click the fork button
>   in the top right corner, and download your own copy of the package
>   code. You would open it (in RStudio), edit the files you want, then
>   build and install your modified version of the package. (This can all
>   be done in RStudio if you install the helper packages, devtools,
>   roxygen2, testthat, etc.) It wouuld certainly be a learning
>   experience, but if the necessary changes are actually minor, it
>   wouldn't be too bad

Now, I dont need to modify anything manually. I just load my GGIR library

```
load(GGIR)
```

… (modified by me) and everything works fine!.

Many thanks.

Regards